# HTML/JS Update one table cell from another table cell

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, mediawiki, wiki

Is it possible to update one table cell from another table cell?

Example:
I have a MediaWiki site, and on **Page A** I have a table cell like this:

```
<td style="background: grey; color: black;"> Proposed</td>
```

I want to be able to update the colour in this cell (say.. to Green) and it will update a completely different table cell on **Page B** (changing it to Green also).

So is there a way to dynamically link two table cells, so that when one cell is changed, the other cell is also update to reflect the same change.

Comment: give them a css class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you're proposing is a good idea. The color of one cell shouldn't depend on the color of some cell in a completely different table. Instead the colors of 
both cells should depend on some common resource.

That common resource could be a CSS style, using the same CSS class for both cells (as Andrew suggested in a comment).

For example, you would define the CSS class `proposed-cell` (most likely in `MediaWiki:Common.css`):

```
.proposed-cell 
{
    color: black;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<td class="proposed-cell">
```

Or it could be a MediaWiki template, that you would reference from cell style.

For example, you could create the page `Template:Proposed color`, whose contents will be `black`.

Then you would use it like this:

```
<td style="color: {{Proposed color}};">
```